# How to block opening files in specified buffers

Tags: buffers

My working vim appearance looks like that:
[image: working vim]

Sometimes I accidentally open file when I am focused on nerd tree buffer and I end up like this:
[image: vim working mess]

So I would like to ask you if there is any way to set vim to block opening files in certain buffers?

Comment: Re-map the "open-file" combination in NerdTree to something more difficult to hit by mistake. Or ditch NerdTree entirely :P

Comment: Would you be so kind to explain to me what do you mean by "ditch NerdTree entirely" ?

Comment: I.e. don't use it until you get more familiar with Vim configuration, and then reading Vim plugins help files. I do assume (perhaps I'm wrong) that you are not too used to Vim, due to the non-specific way in which you have asked your question (appearance, using Vim as an IDE, or coming from one).

Comment: @VanLaser That's right I am beginner with vim. How would you organize appearance? What do you think would be more useful to display than for example NerdTree?

Comment: I would organize appearance later, and just use `:e <tab>` and `:b <tab>` for a while.